# Org-mode: Verbatim Environments

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Say I would like to have some text in a verbatim environment in org-mode where **table shortcuts** are disabled.

For example, consider the following text:

```
|-- 05102013
|   |-- 1826
|   |-- 6500
|   |-- 6501
|   |-- 6502
|   |-- 6503
|   `-- readme
```

If I put it within an `EXAMPLE` literal folder:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
|-- 05102013
|   |-- 1826
|   |-- 6500
|   |-- 6501
|   |-- 6502
|   |-- 6503
|   `-- readme
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

and I accidentally press `<TAB>`  on any line in the text above. org-mode automatically re-organizes the text to make it look like a table:

```
|------------+---------|
|            | -- 1826 |
|            | -- 6500 |
|            | -- 6501 |
|            | -- 6502 |
|            | -- 6503 |
| `-- readme |         |
```

which I don't want. Does org-mode provide any environments or blocks in which the automatic table-creation mechanism is disabled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can wrap your text in a source block like this:

```
#+begin_src text
  |-- 05102013
  |   |-- 1826
  |   |-- 6500
  |   |-- 6501
  |   |-- 502
  |   |-- 6503
  |   `-- readme
#+end_src
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd> inside the block will not reformat your text as a table, but will insert spaces to the next tab stop.

If this still annoys you, you may try `c` instead of `text`, where <kbd>TAB</kbd> will try (and fail) to auto indent instead of adding spaces.

Answer (score 8):

I was gonna propose the same thing as Juancho, except that the specified language would be "fundamental" (instead of "text"), so (almost) nothing would happen.

Answer (score 7):

You can use both Juancho or fniessen suggest, however you can use example environments if you use `C-c '` first to edit the content of the block rather than directly within the org buffer.  Example environments are opened as `fundamental` buffers as well.